# Numpy change shape from (3, 512, 660, 4) to (3,2048,660,1)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensor

I am working on tensorflow and I am having some images of cars in an numpy array with shape `(3, 512, 660, 4)`.

In this, `3` corresponds to a car index, `512*660` is an image size and `4` corresponds to the different sides of a car.

That is, `(1, 512, 660, 1)` corresponds to Car1 - front side image, `(1, 512, 660, 2)` corresponds to Car1 - Left side image and so on.

Now, I want to concat all the images of a car into one image (`2048*660`). That is, I want to reshape `(3, 512, 660, 4)` to `(3, 2048, 660, 1)`.

Can someone help me?

I tried reshape function but it actually overlaps images rather than concatenating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could permute axes to push the last axis up front as the new third axis and reshape. Permuting axes could be handled with `np.swapaxes` or `np.transpose` or `np.rollaxis`, giving us three solutions, like so -

```
a.swapaxes(2,3).reshape(3,2048,660,1)
a.transpose(0,1,3,2).reshape(3,2048,660,1)
np.rollaxis(a,3,2).reshape(3,2048,660,1)
```

If you wanted to have sides-index at the front, transpose it accordingly -

```
a.transpose(0,3,1,2).reshape(3,2048,660,1)
```